# Trouble with 'No such file or directory' Error in PyCharm Using Remote Interpreter

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, virtual-machine

I've run into a bit of a roadblock trying to get a Python script up and running on a Linux VM via PyCharm. My setup involves using a Python interpreter that's on the VM itself, but for some reason I keep getting slapped with a 'No such file or directory' error (Errno 2).

The error message in PyCharm's terminal looks like this:

```
/home/user/bin/python \home\user\pythonProject\chat.py
bash: line 1: cd: home/user/pythonProject: No such file or directory
/home/user/bin/python: can't open file '/home/user/\home\user\pythonProject\chat.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Process finished with exit code 2

Thing is, when I SSH into the VM and manually check, the directory and script are right where they're supposed to be:

user@cody:$ cd /home/user/pythonProject
user@cody:/pythonProject$ ls
chat.py faiss_index lib upload.py
user@cody:~/pythonProject$

For reference, here's a screenshot of the relevant PyCharm settings: (Make sure to insert screenshot of your PyCharm settings, specifically the Python interpreter and Run/Debug Configuration settings).
```

This problem is making my brain explode. A solution would be much appreciated.

[screenshots of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk4HY.png)

Comment: looks like improper slashes (path separators vs escape character) make them all `/`

Comment: Thanks @kenster. The slashes appear to be in the correct order in the path mapping on pycharm. Is there something I am missing?